# If a path is file or directory (Python)

Tags: python

I am trying to list all the files in the current folder and also files in the folders of the current folder. 
This is what I have been upto:

```
import os


def sendFnF(dirList):
        for file in dirList:

                if os.path.isdir(file):
                        print 'Going in dir:',file
                        dirList1= os.listdir('./'+file)
#                       print 'files in list',  dirList1
                        sendFnF(dirList1)
                        print 'backToPrevDirectory:'

                else:
                        print 'file name is',file




filename= raw_input()
dirList= os.listdir('./'+filename)
sendFnF(dirList)
```

This code does get me into folders of the current directory. But when it comes to sub-folders; it treats them as files. 
Any idea what I am doing wrong? 
Thanks in advance,
Sarge.

Comment: You're descending into `"./"+file`, but you never change the *current* directory. (Using, say, `os.chdir()`). You're looking for subdirectories only in the directory where the program was started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prepending `./` to a path does essentially nothing. Also, just because you call a function recursively with a directory path doesn't change the current directory, and thus the meaning of `.` in a file path.

Your basic approach is right, to go down a directory use `os.path.join()`. It'd be best to restructure your code so you `listdir()` at the start of `sendFnF()`:

```
def sendFnF(directory):
    for fname in os.listdir(directory):
        # Add the current directory to the filename
        fpath = os.path.join(directory, fname)

        # You need to check the full path, not just the filename
        if os.path.isdir(fpath):
            sendFnF(fpath)
        else:
            # ...

# ...
sendFnf(filename)
```

That said, unless this is an exercise, you can just use [`os.walk()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.walk)

Comment: Thanks for your help! But i was able to get my code to work by going these lines:
                        prev=os.getcwd();
                        os.chdir(file)
//Recursive call
And then:
                       os.chdir(prev); //Going back to the original directory after function call

Comment: @UsmanKhan That also works of course, I just prefer not poking at the "hidden" process state like that. (For no particular reason really.)